# How to build a custom component in android

Tags: android, custom-component

I want to develop a custom component on android (a word balloon object) and I don't know where to start. Please I need some help

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the topic [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). There is also a [custom view example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/CustomView1.html) in the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) sample code.